# type(list[0]) returns pynput.keyboard._win32.KeyCode

Tags: python, listener, event-listener, pynput

My problem is how `pynput` returns the data (I hope that's how you would say it?).

So what I'm trying to do is have the listener record keyboard input, then use what letters are added to the list to make a string in word. Although, it seems like the letters aren't strings. Instead they return as `pynput.keyboard._win32.KeyCode`

Is there a way to convert that to a python readable string or something?
Like if: i typed `f, t, w`

```
print(type(list[0]), word)
return 'f', ftw
```

what it comes out as so far is

```
f[] pressed
t['f'] pressed
w['f', 't'] pressed
 ['f', 't', 'w'] pressed
['f', 't', 'w'] <class 'pynput.keyboard._win32.KeyCode'> # then basically nothing for word  
[] pressed
```

---

```
from pynput import keyboard


list = []
word = ''.join(list)


def press(key): 
    print(list, 'pressed') 
    if key is not keyboard.Key.space:
        list.append(key)
    elif keyboard.Key.space is key:
        pass
    elif keyboard.Key.enter is key:
        pass


def release(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.space:
        print(type(list[0]), word)
        if word in hkey:
            func()
        list.clear()

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=press, on_release=release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the character from the pressed key by using the `char` attribute of the `pynput.keyboard._win32.KeyCode`. In other words, in your `press` function, you would append `key.char` to the list. Also, I would avoid using `list` as a variable name.

```
def press(key):
    print(_list, 'pressed')
    if key is not keyboard.Key.space:
        _list.append(key.char)         # <-- Note: key.char
    elif keyboard.Key.space is key:
        pass
elif keyboard.Key.enter is key:
    pass
```

Comment: oh. this works. thank you so much. i've tried so many workarounds. things like str(), chr(), and other things that seemed complicated. wish i could properly thank you somehow.

Comment: In your defense, the documentation doesn't seem to mention this property. I found it in the code of one of the examples. Glad to help!

Comment: Thank you for this, it is really helpful.  Is there a way to do it for non-alphanumeric keys such as ':'?

Comment: @skrhee should already work for ':' or any other non-alphanumeric keys, it should work for any character.