# Compare returned data from pynput

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

I need to compare the "output" of pynput listener and do few different things depending on; if the key is a letter or for e.x. enter key. My problem is the way pynput reutrns data, I found partial "fix" in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241868/typelist0-returns-pynput-keyboard-win32-keycode) but that only works for single letters and when you press anything else the program exits. I want to run it in background so it would be great if it woudln't exit when I don't want it to

This is what I have so far;

```py
letters = string.ascii_letters
letters = list(letters)

def on_press(key):
    if key.char in letters:
        print(you pressed a letter)

with Listener(on_press = on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by converting the 'key' variable to string and striping the quotation marks

```py
def on_press(key):
    x = str(key)
    x = x.strip("''")
```